# Python obtain CSS color value of element using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get background color from an image in a class, problem is it gives me an error "invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted".

i tried many versions to get the color (rgb) and every time i get an error and i am confused already because i know there are several ways to do it and i cannot accomplish any.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="reaction-time-test view-splash" ng-class="&quot;view-&quot; + test.getView()" ng-fast-click="test.clickedBg()">
```

CSS CODE:

```
.reaction-time-test.view-splash {
background: #2b87d1;
}
```

What I tried (my final try) - ofc Python

```
check = driver.find_element_by_class_name(".reaction-time-test.view-splash").value_of_css_property('background')
```

also tried:

```
check = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".reaction-time-test.view-splash") # since it only has one element in the css
```

first of all, i found the class, which the color is in, then i tried to get the value of the ONLY element in this class named 'background'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with xpath = //div[@class='reaction-time-test view-splash']

example in java

```
String backColor=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='reaction-time-test view-splash']")).getCssValue("background");
```